# Getting error : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:29 (anonymous function) bootstrap.js:29 (anonymous function)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, visualforce

I'm getting the following error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:29
(anonymous function) bootstrap.js:29
(anonymous function)
```

in my `visualforce` page in the developer console.I'm trying to integrate `twitter-bootstrap` in `Visualforce`

Here is the complete visual force code

```
    <apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->

    <head>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}"
        />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"
        />
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}"
        />
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"
        />

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="force">
            <div class="input-append" align="center" style="padding-top:20px;">
                <input type="text" name="q" class="span2 search-query" placeholder="Snipp or Tag"
                />
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary active"><i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i> A</button>
                    kjhkjdfgdgdfgdfgdfgdfgdgfgdfg
                    <button class="btn btn-primary active"
                    style="margin-right:50px;"><i class="icon-white icon-bullhorn"></i> Fee</button>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Here is a link to the page `jady-developer-edition.ap1.force.com`

Can any one throw some light on what might be wrong.

Comment: So what's around line 29?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to include jquery before including the bootstrap js-file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/1358914798000/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

note that you don't need both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js

Comment: http://jady-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/ ... in the source, the bootstrapfile is included before jquery

Comment: But in my code i have given it above..i dont know why its rendering that way

Comment: I'm not familiar with visual force, but your not including the jquery lib with "apex:includeScript"

Comment: ok thanks dat helped...referring directly wasn't working...i referred it like i included other scripts

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused if you are including `bootstrap.js` before `jquery.js`.
So make sure you are including `jQuery` before `bootstrap`.

**There are other things to check.**

> Also one more possible case is, there could be multiple instances of
>   jQuery in the page. So search for a duplicate version of jQuery and
>   remove them if there is any.

**Find below link for more information.**

[Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)